# Notification Shade icon grayed out

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am trying to show an icon in my notification shade. The icon is a white background with black text. The icon shows up in the status bar, but the notification shade has the icon grayed out. Target sdk is 25. [The notification shade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVxdZ.png) and [The status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oojfm.png)

The code I am using is:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("Where?")
                    .setContentText(text)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.wimbicon);
```

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed this by making the notification icon in Asset Studio such that it has a transparent background. Solves the problem!